# How to stop NotificationListenerService android?

Tags: android, service, notifications, listener

I'm using a NotificationListenerService in my android app that was developed from [kpbird's example](https://github.com/kpbird/NotificationListenerService-Example).  The service runs in the background even after the app is destroyed.  Is there a way to stop this service and start it when app is started?

Answer (score 1):

NotificationListenerService can not be stopped, because after we start the service system will call bindService() . The service will keep a ServiceConnection, then it will not response to the stopService or stopSelf.

As my search result , we also can not remove ServiceConnection from a Service instance.

Answer (score 0):

Create a broadcast receiver inside service which extends NotificationListenerService
like this

```
public class Block_All_Notification2 extends NotificationListenerService {

boolean check=false;

CancelNotificationReceiver mReceiver = new CancelNotificationReceiver();
public static final String Package_Name = "com.muhaiminurabir.notificationblocker";
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return super.onBind(intent);
}

@Override
public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn){
    // Implement what you want here
    // Inform the notification manager about dismissal of all notifications.
    Log.d("Msg", "Notification arrived");
    start_blocking();
   /* if (false){
        cancelAllNotifications();
    }*/
    //Block_All_Notification2.this.cancelAllNotifications();
}

@Override
public void onNotificationRemoved(StatusBarNotification sbn){
    // Implement what you want here
    Log.d("Msg", "Notification Removed");
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    String block = intent.getStringExtra("block");
    Log.d("checking service 1",block+"");
    if (block.equals("yes")){
        check=true;
    }else if(block.equals("no")){
        check=false;
    }
    Log.d("checking service 1",check+"");
    return START_STICKY;

}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction(Package_Name);
    registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
}

public void start_blocking(){
    Log.d("checking service",check+"");
    if (check==true){
        cancelAllNotifications();
    }
}

class CancelNotificationReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d("received service","received");
        String action;
        if (intent != null && intent.getAction() != null) {
            action = intent.getAction();
            if (action.equals(Package_Name)) {
                String block = intent.getStringExtra("block");
                if (TextUtils.equals(block, "no")) {
                    Log.d("checking service 1",block+"");
                    if (block.equals("yes")){
                        check=true;
                        cancelAllNotifications();
                    }else if(block.equals("no")){
                        check=false;
                    }
                    Log.d("checking service 1",check+"");
                } else if (TextUtils.equals(block, "yes")) {
                    Log.d("checking service 1",block+"");
                    if (block.equals("yes")){
                        check=true;
                        cancelAllNotifications();
                    }else if(block.equals("no")){
                        check=false;
                    }
                    Log.d("checking service 1",check+"");
                }
            }
        }
    }

}

}
```

and in your activity add this code to communicate with service which create above

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(Block_All_Notification2.Package_Name);
        intent.putExtra("block", "no");
        context.sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this problem has been solved.

However, I recently found a way to start or stop `NotificationListenerService`, and I would like to share it.

Of course, this is not the official method I think.

Therefore, I think you can just look at it for reference that there is also this way.

I got a hint from the fact that in order to run `NotificationListenerService`, users must be authorized manually.

When the `Start Button` is pressed, the `NotificationListener` permission window is displayed, and a `Toast` Message is displayed to guide the user to request permission.

On the contrary, when the `Stop Button` is pressed, the `NotificationListener` permission window is displayed, and at the same time, a `Toast` Message is displayed to guide the user to revoke permission.

My code is like belows.

```
main_start_service_btn.setOnClickListener {
    if(isNotificationPermissionAllowed()) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Already Starting Service.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }
    else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please allow permission in the next window", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                                                            
startActivity(Intent("android.settings.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SETTINGS"))
    }
}

main_stop_service_btn.setOnClickListener {
    if(isNotificationPermissionAllowed()) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please deny permission in the next window", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                startActivity(Intent("android.settings.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SETTINGS"))
    }
    else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Already Stopped Service.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For your service to terminate you need to ask the android runtime to unbind from your service. Use [`requestUnbind()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService#requestUnbind()).

Comment: Maurizio Vivarelli, a link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

The NotificationListenerService extends Service so yes you can stop a service by calling `stopSelf()` method in Service class.

Look at [`NotificationListenerService`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService.html) and [Services](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html)